# mkdir in Ubuntu does not work

Tags: command-line

I wrote this command in my editor but no result (no warehouse directory)

```
sudo mkdir -p /Downloads/hive/warehouse
```

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by an "editor"?  Why would you expect a result from writing something in an *editor*, instead of the terminal?

And where do you think the folder is created ? Because of the starting `/`, you are asking Ubuntu to create a directory at the root of your system, not in your home or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You did not list your editor, nor your complete script, nor from which privilege/user (rights) you execute the bash script. This is a correct fully functioning syntax to create a folder in `C:\` that is (also visible in Windows 10 explorer) when created in a bash script named `example.sh` (in Windows Subsystem for Linux WSL) Ubuntu 16.04:

```
#!/bin/bash
#First a non-parametric example:
sudo mkdir -p "/mnt/c/exampleFolderOne"

#Secondly, a parametric example, first store the path as a string:
stringName="/mnt/c/exampleFolderTwo"

#Make the actual folder
sudo mkdir "$stringName"
```

The protocol followed to do this was:

1. Start up windows 10 with administrator rights. (So not logging in in the user named "administrator" but just a normal Windows 10 user account that has admin rights.)
2. Open WSL Ubuntu 16.04
3. Aquire root with command `sudo su`
4. in terminal: go to the folder where you want to create the `example.sh` bash script. In this case that was `/home/<username>/maintenance`.
5. enter: `sudo nano example.sh` and press `<enter>`.
6. copy paste the text of the code listed in above in this post.
7. `Ctrl+x` to quit.
8. `Y` to store changes
9. Press `<enter>`
10. Then make the bash script runnable with command (whilst still in the same folder)
11. `chmod +x example.sh`
12. Then run the script with command:
13. `./example.sh`
14. This will create the two folders shown in the attached figure in harddrive `c:/` (which in Ubuntu is reached with `/mnt/c`).
15. The creation of the folder is verified by opening the folder where you create the folders and pressing `F5` or refreshing the explorer view and seeing the folders in the explorer view.

[image: Verification of correct functioning of script, under the assumption that I did not put them there before running the script.]

I assume my solution is trivial and that your problem is has a different cause, but at the very least this can be a form of excluding potential causes (such as typos or procedural errors) of your problem.